# Hibernate Pagination Error near limit - SQL server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, netbeans

Hi I am new to hibernate I am trying to do pagination but I am getting an error near the limit, I will really appreciate any help or guide thank you.

the error pointing in this line in my code

```
q.setFirstResult(0);
q.setMaxResults(2);
```

is it because the SQL server doesn't do limit it uses offset and fetch? 
I am not really sure why maybe someone can guide me thank you

**Configuration XML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate       Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
<!-- Database connection properties -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=tabletest;user=test;password=test123;</property>
<property name="connection.username">test</property>
<property name="connection.password">test123</property>
<!-- JDBC connection pool (using the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!-- Format the generated Sql -->
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<!-- Dont Drop and re-create the database schema on startup,Just update it -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping class="" file="" jar="" package="" resource="com/kb/model/inserthbm.xml"/>
<mapping class="com.kb.model.inserttbl_backup" file="" jar="" package="" resource="com/kb/model/inserthbm_2.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Java Code:**

```java
import com.kb.model.tbl_batch;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.kb.model.tbl_batch;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class PaginationInHibernateWithQueryResults {

  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {
  Configuration c = new Configuration();
  c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
  SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
  Session s = sf.openSession();

  List<tbl_batch> result = null;
  try 
  {
  Query q = s.createQuery("from tbl_batch");
  q.setFirstResult(0);
  q.setMaxResults(2);
  result = q.list();                // first two records, 0 and 1
                                    // printing records using Iterator 
  Iterator it = result.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
    tbl_batch std = (tbl_batch) it.next();
      System.out.println(std.getId() + "  " + std.getusername() + "  " +     std.getpassword());
  }

  q.setFirstResult(2);
  q.setMaxResults(3);               // now you get 3 records starting from 2nd (0, 1, 2)
  result = q.list();                // next three records, 2, 3 and 4
                        // printing elements with JDK 1.5 enhanced for loop
  for(tbl_batch std : result)
  {
 System.out.println(std.getId() + "  " + std.getusername() + "  " + std.getpassword());
  }

  q.setFirstResult(5); 
  // q.setMaxResults(3);               // this statement is not needed as earlier max results size is used
  result = q.list();                // next two records, 5 and 6 (but here, we get only two 
                                    // because total records are 7 (0 to 6))
  for(tbl_batch std : result)
  {
  System.out.println(std.getId() + "  " + std.getusername() + "  " + std.getpassword());
  }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

> ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)     at
>   PaginationInHibernateWithQueryResults.main(PaginationInHibernateWithQueryResults.java:34)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect
>   syntax near 'limit'.

Comment: Can you share the generated SQL?

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean generated sql?

Comment: `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` the result of that

Comment: Hibernate: 
    select
        tbl_batch0_.id as id1_0_,
        tbl_batch0_.username as username2_0_,
        tbl_batch0_.password as password3_0_ 
    from
        tbl_batch tbl_batch0_ limit ?

Comment: the generated sql is this ;   Hibernate: select tbl_batch0_.id as id1_0_, tbl_batch0_.username as username2_0_, tbl_batch0_.password as password3_0_ from tbl_batch tbl_batch0_ limit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured MySQL dialect but are accessing a SQL Server database. You must set SQLServer2012Dialect to tell Hibernate the correct database dialect.

Wrong:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Correct:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are great its working now really appreciate